# How to restore files that allow a PC to boot into Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, raid, windows-installation

Past: I had a problem with a few hard drives from my RAID10 (4 drives mirrored and striped) - they failed simultaneously which prevented me from booting into Windows 7 from the RAID array.

Present: I bought four more drives, installed a basic Win7 with nothing else other than Chrome and my RAID drivers/software. Starting from the most-damaged hard drive, I've allowed the system to rebuild the RAID array.

Problem: When I change my primary disk from my new Win7 hard drive to my RAID array, it still won't allow me to boot. Instead, it goes directly into recovery mode. Yet, when I'm in DOS or boot on my new Win7 drive, I can see some of the files (some appear to be missing).

Question: **What do I need to do to make the RAID array bootable again?** I'd rather do that and have most of my files/programs functional as opposed to starting from scratch and copy/pasting from the old RAID array onto my new install.

Comment: You will need to repair the windows installation using the recovery console of course it might not be POSSIBLE to recover your installation if files are missing.

Comment: Ah, yes, I've attempted the recovery option multiple times so far...